# Using ISO C++0x threads degrades performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing a program in C++ using threads to improve the efficiency.

Basically I'm just creating a huge vector of integers (1 GB) and filling it with random numbers. I executed the program without threads and calculated the time needed.

Now I want to use 2 threads and see the time improvement, but the program is taking much more time with 2 threads than without. Don't know what I'm doing wrong :S

```
#includes...

using namespace std;

//This function just make a for from first to final. Each iteration write a random
//number in the position i of the vector
void generateRandomVector(vector<int> &vec,int first, int final);

//Inside this function i take timestamp2 and calculate the executing time
void calculateTime(clock_t start);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

clock_t start;
    double logaritmo;
    int n = 256*1024*1024;


//Taking timestamp 1
start = clock();

    vector<int> vec(n);

    thread t1(generateRandomVector, ref(vec), 0, n/2);
thread t2(generateRandomVector, ref(vec), n/2, n);

t1.join();
t2.join();

calculateTime(start);
```

I'm passing by reference the vector to both threads because I'm giving them different ranges so they will never be accessing the same position.

If needed, I can also post the `generateRandomVector` function.

Hope someone can help :D

EDIT - `generateRandomVector` function:

```
void generarRandomVector(vector<int> &vec,int first, int final){
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    //PID of each thread
    cout << "PID: " << this_thread::get_id() << "\n";

    for(int i = first; i < final; i++){
        vec[i] = static_cast<int> ((double)rand()*(double)(vec.size()) / ((double)RAND_MAX+1.0));
        vec[i] = vec[i] % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition for `generateRandomVector`?

Comment: Yep, post generateRandomVector and what processor do you have.

Comment: Missclick.I added the function in the main post :P

Comment: FYI stl containers are not inherently thread-safe ... make sure you are only doing read operations to the same container from multiple threads and that no writes will take place elsewhere which may change the vector iterators or size.

Comment: @Kitinz, how many processor cores are available to your operating system?

Comment: 2 cores. Now im trying to protect the acces to the vector with a mutex, but still didnt success :P

Answer (score 7):

Here's the complete C++0x solution, using `<random>` and `<chrono>`:

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void generarRandomVector(std::vector<int> &vec, int first, int final)
{
    std::mt19937_64 e(time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> d(0, 9);
    //PID of each thread
    std::cout << "PID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n";

    for(int i = first; i < final; i++)
        vec[i] = d(e);
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double> sec;
    int n = 256*1024*1024;
    Clock::time_point start = Clock::now();
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    std::thread t1(generarRandomVector, std::ref(vec), 0, n/2);
    std::thread t2(generarRandomVector, std::ref(vec), n/2, n);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    Clock::time_point end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << sec(end-start).count() << " seconds\n";
}
```

Comment: I can't follow all of this. But aren't you seeding both RNGs with the current time? That's a bit careless, isn't it? How about: `std::mt19937_64 e(time(0) + first);`

Comment: The point is, can both threads do write operations over the same vector at the same time? Or should i protect the access to that vector?

Comment: @Kitinz: Because you never read and write to the same area of memory between the threads, you have no data races and therefore no need for a lock. (Contrarily, if you might change the vector itself, even in one thread, the whole thing needs to have a lock around it. Likewise, if a single element was being accessed by multiple threads it would need a lock.)

Comment: And makes sense that 2 threads are slower than no threads because of the cache misses?

Comment: @Kitinz: If you have two cores, you should have two caches. Have you timed the new code?

Comment: @TonyK:  I don't care how you seed it.

Comment: I ran the above code on an Intel Core 2 Duo.  I ran it as shown above, and I ran it again with main calling generarRandomVector(vec, 0, n).  The former completed in about 9 seconds, the latter in about 16 seconds.  I believe this code to  be data race free on this platform.

Comment: @Howard: No, *I* care how *you* seeded it. Using the same 1-second-resolution timer as seed in two concurrent threads is almost guaranteed to result in the two threads generating the same 'random' sequence. Do you see the problem now? Or don't you care?

Comment: @Tony:  Sorry I didn't see your response sooner (been on travel).  My earlier reply to you was poorly worded, my apologies.  When I created this example code I made an attempt to keep it as close as possible to the OP's code so that all readers would be more familiar with my example.  Seeding didn't seem to be an important issue in the OP's problem, so I just seeded the same as in his example.  If you would like to know the best way to seed in this circumstance, I have some really good ideas.  Post a question and I will answer it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use rand().

rand() uses a global state to generate the next number. Also some sources on the web [[1]](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t289984-rand-and-thread-safety.html) claim that it is 'thread-safe', that means that it may use a lock, thus serializing all the calls to rand() and eliminating all the concurrency.

Comment: And the solution, therefore, is to use C++0x's (or Boost's) random number generators, one per-thread.

Comment: You beat me to it, y. What this means is that either (i) `rand()` is thread-safe, which means it must lock access to its internal state each time it is called (so you shouldn't be using it here); or (ii) `rand()` is not thread-safe (so you shouldn't be using it here).

Comment: @TonyK: Well, it could be lock-free and thread-safe, but undoubtedly not.

Comment: @GMan: "It could be..., but undoubtedly not"? In mainstream English, this is a simple contradiction :-)

Comment: @TonyK: I don't see how. "X could be Y only in domain Z, but considering we are not in domain Z, X cannot be Y."

Comment: @GMan: Yes, OK. But that's not what you said!

Comment: @TonyK: I think it is. "Well, it could be lock-free and thread-safe [in theory], but [in practice] undoubtedly not."

Comment: @GMan: Using your template, what you said was "X could be Y, but X cannot be Y." If you stick in some qualifiers, then yes, it's OK, but undoubtedly it's not.

Comment: @TonyK: I understand I may have been unclear ('not' should be 'isn't'), but I still think it's entirely understandable.

Comment: @GMan: "('not' should be 'isn't')": There we have agreement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk of data race with the code given above but a big risk of getting the same data in the two halve parts of the vector.